# How to initialize a contructor which accepts DropDownList array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am not following how to initialize a class constructor which accepts the names of DropDowns in an array as below:

```
public FillDropDowns(DropDownList[] DropDownNameArray)
{
    PopulateDropDown(DropDownNameArray);
}
```

I have a class named FillDropDowns with a method PopulateDropDown.

From my Web Form, I want to create an instance of this class and pass the names of DropDowns.

Comment: I am using it as: FillDropDowns FillDD = new FillDropDowns(cmbLA);  but it is red underlined as Invalid Arguments.

Comment: What is `cmbLA` ? is it an array , can you show the declaration

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong what I understood from your post is that you want to pass a `DropDownList` to the `XXXXXFill` method so the statement of this method populate the `DropDownList`.

Comment: Well it needs an array and not `DropDownList` as parameter, so try `new []{cmbLA }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DropDownList[] parameter = new DropDownList[1]; // create an array of DropDownList 

parameter[0] = DropDownList1; // add DropDownList1 to the array (the reference to the drop down list you want include)

var yourClass = new FillDropDowns(parameter); // make a new instance of the class by passing the array via the constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to take a dropdown list. As per your comments this is what you want.

```
public FillDropDowns(DropDownList DropDownID)
{
    PopulateDropDown(DropDownID);
}
```

Comment: I want to pass an array of DropDowns.